# Button selected (in code) color don't appear correctly in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, button, colors

I have a specific problem. I have two choices buttons in my UI (for my Dialogs) in Unity. The game is only playable with the keyboard. When i open the bubble with the two choices, i select the first button with that :

```
EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(firstButtonGO, new BaseEventData(EventSystem.current));
```

Actually, it work perfectly, except for the color transition tint. The "selected color" doesn't appear. If I move between my buttons (with keyboard), there is no problem and i have my color for each state.

The question is, how do you set the "selected color" on your button when you select it in code ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with this post :

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1142958/buttonselect-doesnt-highlight.html

With that method :

```
    private IEnumerator SelectButtonLater()
    {
        yield return null;
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(null);
        EventSystem.current.SetSelectedGameObject(firstButtonGO, new BaseEventData(EventSystem.current));
    }
```